# Is there a way to configure Mac OS X Snow Leopard server as an Internet gateway with bandwidth tracking per user?

Tags: wifi, osx-server, internet-sharing, network

I'd like to use Mac OS X 10.6.7 Snow Leopard Server as an Internet gateway.  My router would connect to the Internet facing NIC on my Mac Mini server and the internal NIC would connect to a WiFi access point.

I want to be able to track the bandwidth users on the WiFi network are using, but I am aware of the fact that MAC addresses on wireless clients are easily changed.

How can I do bandwidth accounting based on WiFi clients without MAC addresses, logons each time and having the Internet gateway server act as a DHCP server ?

UPDATE - It appears I want to run RADIUS for WiFi auth and usage accounting...is this available in server/daemon form for Mac OS X 10.6.x Snow Leopard Server ?

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: Hm. As you told, the Wifi MAC can be easily changed. So, you cannot use it for the identify. When you don't want `logon` too, how you want identify the client? IMHO, you will need logon.

Comment: I'd like to avoid the logon for ease of use...if I have 5 laptops that always connect, having them logon each time can be a hassle.  If there's no other way, however, I'll go with logons - do you know of a method using logons ?

Comment: RADIUS under 10.6 setup info: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH9052

Comment: can you tell us what you are willing to do with this data maybe a better aproach is to do bandwidth limitation. Otherwise you will have to look in the direction of a proxy or a firewall which is capable for this.

Answer (score 1):

There's a RADIUS server in OS X Server, and it can easily be used for Wi-Fi authentication.

However, traffic accounting is a different thing here. Mac OS X uses Freeradius, which can collect this information, but it is unconfigurable through Server Admin. So, you'll have to set up this by editing proper configuration files manually.